# sum row members conditioned to length in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(id = c("MATMAS","MATMAS","MATMAS","MATMAS","MATMAS",
                             "CFLMAS","CFLMAS","CFLMAS","CFLMAS","CFLMAS","CFLMAS","CFLMAS",
                             "WARMAS","WARMAS","WARMAS","WARMAS","WARMAS"),
                      trailers = c(3,4,3,4,1,
                                2,7,6,2,1,0,4,
                                3,4,NA,NA,NA),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I want is that if the trailers have more (or equal) than six elements then sum up the first 3 elements. If the trailers have less than six elements then  sump up the half of the elements.

Then MATMAS should be 10 (there are five elements, then half of it is 2.5 so goes up to 3 element and the sum is 3+4+3), CFLMAS should be 15 (they are seven elements so it's the sum of the first three elements (2+7+6) and WARMAS should be NA (there are five elements, so we sum up the first three elements but there's a NA so it returns NA).

I tried this approach:

```
dataset %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(looker = ifelse(n()>=6,sum(trailers[1:3,]),sum(trailers[1:ceiling(n()/2),])))
```

but it says that I have an incorrect number of dimensions.

Expected output:

```
id     looker
MATMAS 10
CFLMAS 15
WARMAS NA
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @akrun I added the expected output as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `if/else` as the input and output expected are of `length` 1

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(looker = if(n() >= 6) sum(trailers[1:3]) else 
        sum(trailers[1:(ceiling(n()/2))]))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  id     looker
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 CFLMAS     15
#2 MATMAS     10
#3 WARMAS     NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun, just the answer I needed. Have a great day!